# How to fork the whole Android operating system's code?

Tags: android, version-control, github, open-source, git-fork

I'd like to fork the whole Android operating system's code so that I can make my own modifications to Android. It's best if I can fork the whole thing to repositories on GitHub.

There doesn't seem to be much resources available on how to fork the whole Android operating system's code on Google, maybe someone could provide more details?

In the worst case scenario, would it be feasible for me to fork each individual repository to repositories under my GitHub account?

Comment: http://source.android.com/source/index.html

Comment: @CommonsWare I've seen that page, but I don't think I saw how to fork it?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to fork the entire platform for most cases. You'll need to fork the projects you're making changes to and update the manifest .xmls to point to your server for those projects.

Comment: Do you know any resources on how to edit `manifest.xml` for `repo`?

Comment: This answer seems to be going in the right direction, can someone expand the answer to provide more detail?

Comment: Have a look for example at https://github.com/Galaxy-J5 - they forked all repos modified for the port, and provide  https://github.com/Galaxy-J5/j5_local_manifest to be placed to .repo config to apply those forks over mainline code. Read [Overriding the default Manifest: Local Manifest](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/repo-tips-tricks) for additional info

Answer (score 7):

This http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html is the official guide but there is also a mirror on Github - https://github.com/android

Comment: i don't think there is a "press one button" solution, but maybe with a script you could automate a git clone/push of the github account?

Answer (score 5):

CyanogenMod is an option, follow thier instruction for your devices: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_Guides

Comment: The link is dead now as CM passed away, use LineageOS site instead [How To Build Lineageos Rom For Any Android Device Easily](http://www.lineageosrom.com/2017/01/how-to-build-lineageos-rom-for-any.html)  but there's no much info about the OP question

Comment: CM is back from the dead now